# Sending a JPEG file with embedded no file system little memory controller

Tags: file, embedded, jpeg, wrapper

I have an embedded controller with little memory and NO file system - I have a stream of data available into the system from a JPEG camera. I want to send this data / info as a file over a link(GSM) to a server but do not have a file system on the controller - is there a format for a wrapper I can code the data into before sending it so to the receiving end looks like a JPEG image file ?

Thanks in advance

Col.

Comment: Sending it over what, to what?

Comment: Sending it over a link (GSM) to a server.

Comment: You need to implement a file transfer protocol (e.g. http post, or zmodem). Dynamically creating the file from the stream is probably the easier part. You might need to add some header structures.

Comment: I have no access to the receiving server end other than by the link (GSM / GPRS). I have to construct the file dynamically prior to sending. All I need is the relevant header, format and footer of the file that would exist for transmission - I will then add all the necessary data.

Answer (score 0):

JPEG is just a stream of data. It does not have to be in a file. It sounds like you just need to send the data stream from the camera and pass it on. There should be an  marker, a bunch of data  market.

That's what your web browser/web server do.

Comment: Thanks - but the files must exist on the server all time stamped. There is no browser only an embedded system and a server.

Comment: If you need a time stamp, you can insert it into the JPEG stream in an COM or APPn marker.